# Mongodb multivalue with oData, collection data lost

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, odata, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to use MongoDB as my data and have oData to generate feed in C# ASP.Net. My class looks like this:

```
public class Student
{
    String FirstName;
    String LastName;
    list<course> classes;
} 

public class Course
{
    string id;
    string name;
}
```

I can add the data in mongodb, and get back it JSON. But when I get the feed through oData, collection course is just not displayed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using $expand?

http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#ExpandSystemQueryOption

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks. 
I tried using expand but apparently, it doesn't work with web API. It returned 406 bad request.

Comment: Anikita, $expand is coming to WebAPI, but probably not for 2-3 months at least.

Comment: @AlexJames Thanks. I have been reading your blog, it is really helpful. I have been working on this for a long time and I dont think we can wait until 2-3 months. Is there any workaround you can suggest?

Comment: @AnikitaB - have you looked at doing a custom data service provider in WCF Data Services?

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT Thanks. I dont know much about it, I will look into it.

Comment: @AnikitaB - back to Alex's blog for the most comprehensive walkthrough of creating one. You also might be able to make a reflection provider work for you (it's substantially easier) but my guess is you might hit the wall pretty quickly with that.

Comment: If you go down the route of creating an OData WCF service they you might like to take a look at this, http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/. It works pretty well against MongoDB and uses the reflection provider.

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT thanks. I tried that. But as I am using mongoDB WCF is of no use to me, as per my understanding WCF will need a SQL (type) database, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: WCF Data Services does not require a relational database, or even a database for that matter. What you choose to back it with is your prerogative. I haven't tried the WCF DS Toolkit, but it sounds like it might work well according to @SCB.

Comment: Hello All, thanks for your responses. I ended up removing the collections to a new class and writing a new controller for it. Everything is working now. Thanks alot once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at MongOData MongoDB OData provider, described in my blog post:
http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2012/05/19/expose-mongodb-data-as-odata-feed-using-mongodata-provider.aspx

It's still under development, but I've been successfully using it in several projects.

Comment: Hi Vagif, Thanks! I had referred your blog when I was looking for solutions. We have decided to move away from mvc and get to WCF as it was giving us more flexibility.